# Python Regex match item in string and return item if sub-item exist

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings and i want to extract the token in the string that matches a sub-string by partially matching that substring until a whitespace.

```
l=[u'i like cats and dogs',u'i like catnip plant', u'i like cars']
for s in l:
    if "cat" in s:
        #match cat until whitespace
        print re.search("(cat).*[^\s]+",s).groups()
```

However This returns cat only:

```
(u'cat',)
(u'cat',)
```

I want:

```
cats
catnip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to match any word that starts with 'cat':

```
import re
l=[u'i like cats and dogs',u'i like catnip plant', u'i like cars']
for s in l:
    if "cat" in s:
        print re.search("cat\w*",s).group()
```

this returns:

```
cats
catnip
```

You can also use:

```
print re.search("cat[^\s]*",s).group()
```

or

```
print re.search("cat\S*",s).group()
```

DETAILS:

You have these problems with your regex: `"(cat).*[^\s]+"`. The first is that you are only grouping "cat" since it is the only substring in parenthesis, so you are only printing "cat" when using `.groups()` to print the groups in your match. The second is that `.*`, which follows `(cat)`, matches any character zero or more times including a space so the regex matches the whole string before getting to the "not a space" char match, `[^\s]`.

Another issue is that you are using `.groups()` which returns a tuple with all of the groups in the match. In your case, you only have one group, so it returns a tuple with only one group. For instance:

```
l=[u'i like cats and dogs',u'i like catnip plant', u'i like cars']
for s in l:
    if "cat" in s:
        print re.search("(cat\w*)",s).groups()
```

returns these tuples (each with only one group):

```
(u'cats',)
(u'catnip',)
```

Since you only have one group you don't need a tuple, so you can use `.group()`:

```
print re.search("(cat\w*)",s).group()
```

for it to return just the matched group:

```
cats
catnip
```

Furthermore, since the group is the whole match, you don't need to group it (ie. you don't need the parenthesis). `.group()` defaults to `.group(0)` which returns the whole match:

```
print re.search("cat\w*",s).group()
```

prints what you want.

Finally, note that `*` is used after `\w`, `[^\s]`, and `\S` so that it matches the word `cat` also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to match any non-whitespace chars after `cat` and `re.search(r"cat\S*",s)` is enough for this.

```
import re
l=[u'i like cats and dogs',u'i like catnip plant', u'i like cars']
for s in l:
    #match cat until whitespace
    m = re.search(r"cat\S*",s)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/TpXvvh)

The pattern matches:

- `cat` - a `cat` substring
- `\S*` - 0 or more non-whitespace characters (if you only need to match *letters*, replace with `[^\W\d_]*` pattern).

To make the pattern case insensitive, pass `re.I` flag to the `re.search` method, or add `(?i)` inline modifier version at the start of the pattern.